# Associate to admin after registration in front end?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, customer-account, websites

I have found many questions from people who have had the same problem. But I cannot find a solution.

**Problem:**
All customers who register on the front end (default Store, Website ID: 1) should be associated to admin.

I´m forced to allow login on all websites, so customers can login on the front end.

Anyone have an idea on how this bug can be solved?

Thanks
Manuel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the back end by doing the following:

1. Go to System->Configuration
2. Select Website Configuration Scope: (default Store, Website ID: 1)
3. Go to Customers->Customer Configuration
4. In Create New Account Options select the group you want to use.

Done.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, unfortunately, customers become only a fixed customer group, the associate to website is still "Admin".

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: habe place a screenshot in post.